# Hello! How do I get the program to recognize the largest number with input+output dialog boxes with two integers? JAVA

Tags: java

I've been working on this for about two hours now and am now looking for help. My main issue is that I can't seem to put the largest number in to effect. I don't know what is wrong. Do I use the MIN/MAX that I've seen a few people use? Does that work with JOptionPane? Program is down below.

```
import java.util.Scanner
public class Blah
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

      double num1;
      double num2;
      String inputted_text;

     inputted_text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
     inputted_text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number:");

     num1=input.nextInt();
     num2=input.nextInt();

     if(num1>num2)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first number is bigger than the second number.");

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The second number is bigger than the first number.";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use the largest `int` possible, for instance, you can use `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: How would that look in my program if you don't mind me asking? I am pretty new to JAVA, been using it for about two weeks now.

Comment: You could code something like `int maxValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` The same would work with `double`, except you would have to use `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using both the swing and console for input. Try the following code to see if this is the desired behavior, you are looking for. You will want to add a try/catch to verify that the user types in a valid number.

```
double num1;
double num2;
String inputted_text1;
String inputted_text2;

inputted_text1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number: ");
num1 = Integer.parseInt(inputted_text1);
inputted_text2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number:");
num2 = Integer.parseInt(inputted_text2);
if (num1 > num2) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first number is bigger than the second number.");
} else {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The second number is bigger than the first number.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you help.